# how to avoid mutating this.state or redux object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

For example, if I want to do any operation on `this.state` or some other object, such as `Object.keys(this.state).map()` to get access to all the values in the object.

Is it bad practice to do this?

```
Object.keys(this.state).map(k => this.state[k]);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React, you should only mutate `this.state` using `this.setState()` so that React knows when to re-render components.

The line of code you've written is fine, because you're not actually modifying the state object. You've already created a new array using `Object.keys`.

If however, you want to copy `this.state` without modifying it, try the following.

```
const state = {...this.state};

// Or 

const state = Object.assign({}, this.state);
```

Answer (score 0):

React Mutating State.

```
let state = {
    age    : 25,
    name   : 'Robin',
    friends: ['Barney', 'Ted']
}
```

**Change Age**

```
this.setState({age: 26})
```

**Change Name**

```
this.setState({name: 'Lily'})
```

**Add Friend**

```
this.setState({ 
    friends: this.state.friends.concat(['Marshall'])
})
```

Try this library [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) for complex state updates.